# Customize Calendar control

Tags: asp.net, calendar

I want to customize the calendar control in such a way that calendar starts from current date.
E.g. Today is 29th February then it should show the first date 9th February in the calendar.

Is it possible to do with asp.net calendar control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ca set the [SelectedDate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.selecteddate.aspx) propery. Assuming your calendar name is MyCal, you can set the first month date in this way:

```
myCal.SelectedDate = New Date(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1)
```

ADDENDUM

Try with this code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyCal.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
}

protected void MyCal_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Day.Date < DateTime.Now.Date)
    {
        e.Cell.Visible = false;
    }
}

protected void MyCal_VisibleMonthChanged(object sender, MonthChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewDate.Month == DateTime.Now.Date.Month - 1) 
    {
         MyCal.SelectedDate = e.PreviousDate;
         MyCal.VisibleDate = e.PreviousDate;
    }
}
```

In this way you:

1. Set the current date
2. Hide the previous day
3. Disable previous month browsing

Comment: I want to start my calendar grid from current date. All the past dates of should not show in the month of current date grid but the dates of next month should show in the current date .grid

Comment: Please, give up our pay!: your feedback

Comment: We are here to help and learn. Follow stackoverflow rules to improve this exiting website. http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 2):

By default the `<asp:Calendar />` control displays the current month.

This can be overriden using the `VisibleDate` property if you like.

Could you please clarify what you mean that it should start from todays date? What should happen to the rest of the days of the month?

If you want to grey out or disable the other days in the month, hook into the `OnDayRender` event which will run when each day is rendered and it gives you access to the date and the cell so you can do something like.

```
protected void Calendar1_OnDayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e) {
    if(e.Day.Date < DateTime.Now) {
        e.Cell.CssClass="disabled";
    }
}
```

The other property you need to know of is the `SelectedDate` property. Setting this is the equivalent of clicking on that particular date.

Comment: Yes visible property can be used. But i want that our calendar start from current date and it includes all the dates of next month also.